# Tableau marks card size

Tags: size, settings, tableau-api

Does anyone knows how to customize size of a Marks card in Tableau?

On Marks card I have multiple measures so every time i want to get to the bottom I have to scroll. I have plenty of unused space below so I started to wonder if there is an option to change the size of this card so it would show all of the measures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdnoi.png)

Comment: Nope,it doesn't allow to increase the size to a single fit but if you think its a good to have sizing of the marks shelf you can send your request to Tableau support team.

Comment: pity :/ Thanks for quick answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no such particular option where you can `resize` your marks card.

However, you can drag it to top / right and see if your marks fit in there.

You might like to place this as **idea** in Tableau Community Forums .
https://community.tableau.com/community/ideas